# Regex permits forbidden strings - can anyone advise?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to test that a string is an exact match for one of a number of patterns.

I think I can do this with

```
myRegex.IsMatch(testString) && myregex.Match.ToString()==testString
```

but can this be done in the regex pattern itself?

I want to test that testString matches either `DOC` or `EMAIL` exactly, or `HTML::sometexthere` or `CSV::sometexthere`.
It must not match `DOC::sometexthere`, for example - that should be a 'fail'

My current regex pattern is `^(DOC|EMAIL)|((CSV|HTML)::.+)`, but that allows forbidden strings such as `DOC::sometexthere`

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern is correct, but you must add a 'end of string' anchor `$`:

```
 ^((DOC|EMAIL)|((CSV|HTML)::.+))$
```

Note that I have enclosed the two possibilities inside parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks - I had already tried the $ idea, but it was the extra pair of brackets that did the trick.

Comment: @NeilHaughton: Yes, If you omit this, the end anchor is only for the second part of your pattern.

Comment: I guess ^(somethinghere)$ means "begin and end with the same thing", effectively meaning exact match, but could it also match "DOCDOC", for example?

Comment: @NeilHaughton: No, it doesn't. `^` means "start of the string", `$` means "end of the string", that's all.

Comment: So why did the outer enclosing brackets make a difference? Doesn't that mean 'must start with everything in the brackets, and must end with everything in the brackets'? I'm trying to understand why that's not ambiguous, permitting DOCDOC instead of just DOC (for example)

Answer (score 1):

The following regex should do exactly what you ask: `((DOC|EMAIL)|((HTML|CSV)::.*))`

Was tested on the following strings:

- DOC - match
- EMAIL - match
- EMAIL::someTextHere - no match
- DOC::someTextHere - no match
- HTML::SomeTextHere - match
- CSV::someTextHere - match

**UPDATE**
Change it to this and it should sattisfy your needs completely.

```
((DOC|EMAIL)$|((HTML|CSV)::.+))
```

Added the $ so it wouldn' capture the DOC in DOC::sometext changed the * to + so it should atleast contain one character behind the ::

Comment: I need to use "+" instead of "*" : there must be something after the :: or it is invalid too.

Comment: The * can be replaced with a + indeed. (changing it from 0 or more to 1 or more matches)